# How do I make an Angular UI Datepicker NOT Required

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-datepicker

I have a form with many fields, including several datepickers (Angular UI Bootstrap).

```
<div name="mainForm" ng-form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="dt" 
                   class="form-control"
                   ng-model="dt"
                   is-open="opened" 
                   datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <p class="text-danger" ng-show="mainForm.$invalid">Invalid!</p>
</div>
```

I'm using Angular validation w/ the form. We have some required fields, but the dates are not. If you enter a date and remove it, it marks the form invalid. I created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1iGDEnnpEOtBPymPPiLS?p=preview) to demonstrate this.

Is there a way around this?

Note: It also logs this error in the console when you clear the date out.

*Datepicker directive: "ng-model" value must be a Date object, a number of milliseconds since 01.01.1970 or a string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date.*

Comment: It's a bug: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3835

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of the code there is a `$datepickerSuppressError` value that you can set to true which will hide the console error. [You can see in the code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/0.14.3/src/datepicker/datepicker.js#L97) that it checks if the date is NaN and then displays the console error if `$datepickerSuppressError` is still false.

However, having said that, there is still a way to work around the issue of the form being invalid. You will just need to add an additional check to see if `mainForm.$error.date` is set, or something similar to this.

For example you can change your button to have this instead:

```
ng-disabled="mainForm.$invalid && !mainForm.$error.date"
```

Which will leave your button enabled even though the directive has set an error on the date and it should disable if any other field is invalid.

Comment: Can I somehow remove the $error.date when the date is empty? Because on my form the date is also optional and when you remove it, there will be an error.

Comment: @adiii4 I don't believe the current version (0.14.3) has this issue. This question was asked with 0.13.0. I would make sure your version is up-to-date and then open a new question if you still have an issue.

Comment: I fixed it! There was something wrong with a validation directive I coded. But thanks for your help!